# Expand numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, numpy

I have a list of numbers:

```
[10,20,30]
```

What I need is to expand it according to a predefined increment. Thus, let's call `x` the increment and `x=2`, my result should be:

```
[10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,.....,38]
```

Right now I am using a for loop, but it is very slow and I am wondering if there is a faster way.

EDIT:

```
newA = []
for n in array:
    newA= newA+ generateNewNumbers(n, p, t)
```

The function generates new number simply generate the new numbers to add to the list.

EDIT2:
To better define the problem the first array contains some timestamps:

```
[10,20,30]
```

I have two parameters one is the sampling rate and one is the sampling time, what I need is to expand the array adding between two timestamps the correct number of timestamps, according to the sampling rate.
For example, if I have a sampling rate 3 and a sampling time 3 the result should be:

```
[10,13,16,19,20,23,26,29,30,33,36,39]
```

Comment: Show your working loopy code? The problem isn't really clear from the sample, too many assumptions there it seems.

Comment: can you publish your code?

Comment: why it should stop at 38 , any condition  for that

Comment: Yes sorry, I will update the question with more details.

Comment: It looks like you could use the smallest and largest values in a range somehow: range(small, large+constant, increment), but as others have mentioned, there are lots of assumptions in your question that you need to clarify.

Comment: You can convert your loop to a list comprehension. For further savings it will depend on whether your `generateNewNumbers` can be vectorized.

Comment: I have updated the question, thank you.@alkanen

Comment: what would you want if  l=[10,27,100] ?

Comment: if the sampling rate is 3 and the sampling time is 4 i want:
[10,14,18,22,27,31,35,39,100,104,108,112]
@B.M.

Comment: thanks. what was unclear for me  was that the `l`  has regular step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the same set of increments to each time stamp using `np.add.outer` and then flatten the result using `ravel`.

```
import numpy as np
a = [10,20,35]
inc = 3
ninc = 4
np.add.outer(a, inc * np.arange(ninc)).ravel()
# array([10, 13, 16, 19, 20, 23, 26, 29, 35, 38, 41, 44])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprhensions but I'm not sure if I understand the stopping condition for the last point inclusion

```
a = [10, 20, 30, 40]
t = 3
sum([[x for x in range(y, z, t)] for y, z in zip(a[:-1], a[1:])], []) + [a[-1]]
```

will give

```
[10, 13, 16, 19, 20, 23, 26, 29, 30, 33, 36, 39, 40]
```

Comment: Two things more: also 40 should be expanded to 40,43,46,49, and I need to save the result in a new array leaving the input unchanged. thank you. @percusse

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni expanded until what number ? How do I determine 50 from `a`? Should I assume periodicity? This doesn't modify the input by the way just assign it to a variable.

Comment: This approach does not work, actually I don't know why but it produces an array with more item than they should be. You can see the answer to B.M. to understand better what I want. @percusse

Comment: Moreover this approach is more slow than the others

Comment: @GuidoMuscioni I would really doubt that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `range` and `itertools.chain`

```
l = [10,20,30]
x = 3
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*[range(i,i+10,x) for i in l]))
#Output:
#[10, 13, 16, 19, 20, 23, 26, 29, 30, 33, 36, 39]
```

Comment: this returns exactly l, the input array

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bunch of good answers already. But I would advise numpy and linear interpolation.

```
# Now, this will give you the desired result with your first specifications
# And in pure Python too
t = [10, 20, 30]
increment = 2
last = int(round(t[-1]+((t[-1]-t[-2])/float(increment))-1)) # Value of last number in array
# Note if you insist on mathematically "incorrect" endpoint, do:
#last = ((t[-1]+(t[-1]-t[-2])) -((t[-1]-t[-2])/float(increment)))+1
newt = range(t[0], last+1, increment)
# And, of course, this may skip entered values (increment = 3

# But what you should do instead, when you use the samplerate is
# to use linear interpolation
# If you resample the original signal,
# Then you resample the time too
# And don't expand over the existing time
# Because the time doesn't change if you resampled the original properly
# You only get more or less samples at different time points
# But it lasts the same length of time.
# If you do what you originally meant, you actually shift your datapoints in time
# Which is wrong.
import numpy

t = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
oldfs = 4000 # 4 KHz samplerate
newfs = 8000 # 8 KHz sample rate (2 times bigger signal and its time axis)
ratio = max(oldfs*1.0, newfs*1.0)/min(newfs, oldfs)
newlen = round(len(t)*ratio)
numpy.interp(
    numpy.linspace(0.0, 1.0, newlen),
    numpy.linspace(0.0, 1.0, len(t)),
    t)
```

This code can resample your original signal too (if you have one). If you just want to cram in some more timepoints in between, you can also use interpolation. Again, don't go over the existing time. Although this code does it, to be compatible with the first one. And so that you can get ideas on what you can do.

```
t = [10, 20, 30]
increment = 2
last = t[-1]+((t[-1]-t[-2])/float(increment))-1 # Value of last number in array
t.append(last)
newlen = (t[-1]-t[0])/float(increment)+1 # How many samples we will get in the end
ratio = newlen / len(t)
numpy.interp(
    numpy.linspace(0.0, 1.0, newlen),
    numpy.linspace(0.0, 1.0, len(t)),
    t)
```

This though results in an increment of 2.5 instead of 2. But it can be corrected. The thing is that this approach would work on floating time points as well as on integers. And fast. It will slow down if there is a lot of them, but until you reach some great number of them it will work pretty fast.