# Expand number with a dynamic sample rate

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have a list of timestamps (second resolution) that represent the id of some sensor readings. I need to add a milliseconds resolution following the number of sample per seconds. An example below:

> [1344397048000, 1344397048000, 1344397048000, 1344397049000,
>   1344397049000, 1344397049000, 1344397049000, 1344397049000,
>   1344397049000, 1344397050000, 1344397050000]

As you can see the number of samples change with respect to a timestamp in particular:

```
Counter({1344397048000: 3, 1344397049000: 6, 1344397050000: 2})
```

What I want is the initial list of timestamps with milliseconds for each instance:

> [1344397048000.0, 1344397048333.3333, 1344397048666.6667,
>   1344397049000.0, 1344397049166.6667, 1344397049333.3333, 1344397049500.0, 1344397049666.6667, 1344397049833.3333, 1344397050000.0, 1344397050500.0]

To do that now I am using loops and this code is extremely slow, so I was wondering if there is a way to make it quicker.

The code I am using:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

x = [1344397048000, 1344397048000, 1344397048000, 1344397049000, 1344397049000, 1344397049000, 1344397049000, 1344397049000, 1344397049000, 1344397050000, 1344397050000]

d = Counter(x)

result = []
for time in np.unique(x):
    for i in range(0,d[time]):
        result.append(time+i*1000/d[time])
```

This question is directly related to this one: [Expand numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617045/expand-numbers-in-a-list)
However, this time the increment parameter is dynamic.

Comment: Is the spacing between the unique timestamps always the same?  That is, are the values in `np.diff(np.unique(x))` gauranteed to all be the same?

Comment: no they can be different @WarrenWeckesser

Comment: The code that you use appears to assume a fixed timestep of 1000.  That is, your code spreads out the repeat values over a time interval of length 1000.  Is that what you want to do even if the time to the next unique timestamp is more than 1000?  Or should the adjusted values be spread out over the interval between the observed unique timestamps?  Can the difference between unique timestamps ever be less than 1000?  What should the adjusted values be in that case?

Comment: Oh ok I get your point, yes for each unique timestamp 1000 is the length